# drop multiple rows in pandas based on date and join with other files based on month?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, twitter

I have multiple csv files every file consists of 3 columns. date, ID and tweet I want to drop the rows before a certain date which is November 2016

every row in the file look like this 
`

```
id                    created_at                    text
907539404893421568  2017-09-12 09:40:30 #عمرو_حمزاوي يكتب: متى يراجعون  أنفسهم؟ https:/...
```

I tried this to get the year and month of each tweet to play with them but it seems so naive and I don't like it and I'm having trouble getting the format of the date

```
x = []
for i in df['created_at']:
    #g = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(i))
    yourdate = dateutil.parser.parse(i)
    date = [yourdate.month, yourdate.year]
    x.append(date)
```

Is there a better way to do so and if so How can I drop all the rows before a certain date, and after that how can I join all the rows that fall in the same month into one row and finally how can I join it with other files with the same format ??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is this `#أنفسهم؟` next to your dates?

Comment: nothing just a hashtag, it is a part of the text of the tweet

Comment: `df = df.set_index('created_at', drop=False)['2016-11':]`

Comment: `df = df[df['created_dat'] > '2016-11-01']` to collect rows after Nov 2016.

Comment: df = df[df['created_dat'] > '2016-11-01']  this one works, but I don't get it how can I do that with a string and how can I join rows with in the same month now into one row that means the data frame will only have 11 rows ?